# How do I write Set-Content to a file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file-io

I'm doing a number of string replacements in a PowerShell script.

```
foreach ($file in $foo) {
    $outfile = $outputpath + $file
    $content = Get-Content ($file.Fullname) -replace 'foo','bar'
    Set-Content -path $outfile -Force -Value $content 
}
```

I've validated (through console logging of `$outfile` and `$content`, which I don't show in the above code) that the proper files are being selected, the `-replace` is accuratly updating the content, and the `$outfile`s are being created. However, each of the output files a 0 byte file. The `Set-Content` line does not appear to be writing the data to the files. I've tried piping `Set-Content` to `Out-File`, but that just gives me an error.

When I replace `Set-Content` with `Out-File`, I get a runtime error `Out-File : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'path'.` even though I can output `$outfile` to the console and see that it's a valid path.

Is there an additional step (like a close-File or save-file command) I need to take or a different order in which I need to pipe something to get the `$content` to write to my `$outfile`? What component am I missing?

Comment: Did you verify that $content has proper content?

Comment: Yes...I've added that the `-replace` is accurately modifying the contents when I log `$content` to the console...

Comment: You don't have -Path parameter in Get-Content. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes...thanks. Just updated that as well.

Comment: In this line:  $content = Get-Content -replace 'foo','bar'
you appear to have neglected to tell it where Get-Content is supposed to be getting content from.  I suspect that might explain the 0 byte files.

Comment: @mjolinor - That was a typo---since corrected. When I output `$content` to the console, the replacements are accurate, so I know that's working.

Comment: Does $file holds full path to the input file or just a file name?

Comment: That still can't work. It's going to think -replace is a parameter of Get-Content.  i'd use: $content = (Get-Content $file.Fullname) -replace 'foo','bar'

Comment: @sha `$file` is the filename only, `$outfile` appends the path to the head of the file for OUTPUT. This is the file that's getting created as a zero byte file. If I understand properly, `$file.Fullname` references the full path of the source file, which, based on console output, appears to be reading properly.

Answer (score 5):

The `Out-File` cmdlet does not have a `-Path` parameter, however it does have a `-FilePath` parameter. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
Out-File -FilePath test.txt -InputObject 'Hello' -Encoding ascii -Append;
```

You will also need to wrap the `Get-Content` command in parentheses, as it does not have a parameter called `-replace`.

```
(Get-Content -Path $file.Fullname) -replace 'foo','bar';
```

I'd also recommend adding the `-Raw` parameter to `Get-Content`, so that you ensure that you're only dealing with a single line of text, rather than an array of strings (one `[String]` per line in the text file).

```
(Get-Content -Path $file.Fullname -Raw) -replace 'foo','bar';
```

There isn't enough information to completely understand what's going on, but here is a filled out example of what I think you're trying to do:

```
# Create some dummy content (source files)
mkdir $env:SystemDrive\test;
1..5 | % { Set-Content -Path $env:SystemDrive\test\test0$_.txt -Value 'foo'; };

# Create the output directory
$OutputPath = mkdir $env:SystemDrive\test02;

# Get a list of the source files
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:SystemDrive\test -Filter *.txt;

# For each file, get the content, replace the content, and 
# write to new output location
foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    $OutputFile = '{0}\{1}' -f $OutputPath.FullName, $File.Name;
    $Content = (Get-Content -Path $File.FullName -Raw) -replace 'foo', 'bar';
    Set-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $Content;
}
```